# How to change the navbar after a user is logged in?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I currently have 2 different navbars. One with Login and Sign up at the top and one with Account. I want the navbar to change to the one with Account after a user is logged in. My registration and login system is already working, so that won't have to change (connected to a database). Don't mind the names, it's for a school project.

These are my 2 navbars:

```
<div class="navbar">
    <a class="active" href="Boomba.php">Boomba</a>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn">Boomba News 
            <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="Newnews.php">New News</a>
            <a href="Deadnews.php">Dead News</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <a href="Boombastore.php">Boomba Store</a>
    <a href="BoombaForm.php">Contact</a>
    <div class="floatr">
        <a href="0register.php">Sign Up</a>
        <a href="0login.php">Login</a>
        <a href="welcome.php">Account</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I currently have this at the top of the page:

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
```

Please let me know if there's an easier way overall to make this happen as well, this is my first website.

Thanks in advance :)

**Edit:**

My config file:

```
<?php

define('DB_SERVER', '-');
define('DB_USERNAME', '-');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '-');
define('DB_NAME', '-');

$link = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
?>
```

My Login file:

```
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) && $_SESSION["loggedin"] === true){
    header("location: welcome.php");
    exit;
}

require_once "0config.php";

$username = $password = "";
$username_err = $password_err = "";

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

    if(empty(trim($_POST["username"]))){
        $username_err = "Please enter username.";
    } else{
        $username = trim($_POST["username"]);
    }

    if(empty(trim($_POST["password"]))){
        $password_err = "Please enter your password.";
    } else{
        $password = trim($_POST["password"]);
    }

    if(empty($username_err) && empty($password_err)){
        $sql = "SELECT id, username, password FROM users WHERE username = ?";

        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_username);

            $param_username = $username;

            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);

                if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) == 1){                    
                    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $id, $username, $hashed_password);
                    if(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)){
                        if(password_verify($password, $hashed_password)){
                            session_start();

                            $_SESSION["loggedin"] = true;
                            $_SESSION["id"] = $id;
                            $_SESSION["username"] = $username;                            

                            header("location: welcome.php");
                        } else{

                            $password_err = "The password you entered was not valid.";
                        }
                    }
                } else{
                    $username_err = "No account found with that username.";
                }
            } else{
                echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }
        }

        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }

    mysqli_close($link);
}
?>
```

Comment: Check session is set? If the session set then write the nav menu code inside if condition

Comment: @Mjm How exactly do i do that? I'm completely new to PHP

Comment: you need to show us your login method, to see what are you storing in session.

Comment: What you are storing in your session to login the user?

Comment: I edited the question and added my config and login files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are duplicating a lot of code for your navbar here. You could do something like this if the other parts of your navbar don't need to change :

```
<div class="navbar">
    <a class="active" href="Boomba.php">Boomba</a>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn">Boomba News
            <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="Newnews.php">New News</a>
            <a href="Deadnews.php">Dead News</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <a href="Boombastore.php">Boomba Store</a>
    <a href="BoombaForm.php">Contact</a>
    <div class="floatr">
        <?php if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin']): ?>
            <a href="welcome.php">Account</a></li>
        <?php else: ?>
            <a href="0register.php">Sign Up</a></li>
            <a href="0login.php">Login</a></li>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

After the login operation, you must load the user-specific data to `$_SESSION` array. Imagine you have stored the user data to `$_SESSION` then you can check the `$_SESSION` value exist or not.

A sample code is given below. If you don't understand please let me know.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if (isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) && ($_SESSION["loggedin"] == TRUE)) {
        //write a nav menu html code here
        ?>
        <div>
            nav-1
        </div>
        <?php
    } else {
        //write another nav menu html code here
        ?>
        <div>
            nav-2
        </div>
        <?php
    }
?>
```

Comment: Hi, if I try to add my code (probably wrong) I get a double navbar when I am logged in. I added my html codes but I had to put a '?>' after the 'if' and 'else' to make it register the html. I guess I did something wrong. I edited my question as well so you can see my login and config codes.